# mockito's method call counting

Tags: java, mockito

I have some problems to correctly anticipate method call counts (the parameter for times). So how is mockito counting method calls. Setting breakpoints where the method is called and counting stops on this points yields other counts!

So does the count some how depent on parameters or is it parameter independent? Here is an example that confuses me (its not the first time):

```
verify(view).setBoxes(eq(attribute), eq(State.some), checkBoxes.capture());
assertThat(checkBoxes.getValue(), allOf(hasEntry(value1, true), hasEntry(value2, false), hasEntry(value3, false)));

//doing some stuff to provoke 2nd call
verify(view, times(2)).setBoxes(eq(attribute), eq(State.some), checkBoxes.capture());
assertThat(checkBoxes.getValue(), allOf(hasEntry(value1, true), hasEntry(value2, true), hasEntry(value3, false))); 

//doing some stuff to provoke 3rd call - with times(3) it fails
verify(view, times(2)).setBoxes(eq(attribute), eq(State.some), checkBoxes.capture());
assertThat(checkBoxes.getValue(), allOf(hasEntry(value1, true), hasEntry(value2, true), hasEntry(value3, true)));
```

The test above passes. As you see the captured value changes each time. per debugger I can cleanly prove 3 calls with the parameters checked above. I also checked the id/hash of view object: it is a test singleton, all calls go to same instance.

But why the hell it is failing with `times(3)` ? That is not the first time I am stumbling across irreproducible (with debugger) method calls counts. My hope is that I only missunderstood the logic of method call counting - is this so?

Comment: If you count manually, are you certain the argument matchers match? You can try changing the eq() to any() and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us more code than this?  There are so many possible reasons for this failure, and it's hard to tell what's happening when all we have are the asserts and verifies.

Comment: what parts of code do you need? the complete test? or parts of object under test? but tell me: is the method count value specific (one count for each parameter kombination)?
It is not the first tim i encounter such problem - but this time i want to know what is happening.